# Is it possibile customize the CSV file exported from a kibana discovery? if yes, how can i do it?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, elk

i have done a dashboard in kibana with some discoveries, then i downloaded the default CSV generated . I have opened them but the excel file has a very bad style. How can i customize it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own Discover format by adding and removing fields via the field list on the left, then download that format

[image]